# ShareLatex - change the word "Definition" to other word

Tags: theorems, languages

I'm currently writing my thesis in ShareLatex (I'm a romanian) and I can't change the words "Definition", "Theorem", etc... to "Definitia", "Teorema". I tried the syntax used with the `babel` package but it still doesn't work. I tried the `\renewcommand` to change "Contents" to "Cuprins" and it worked.

Please help me.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) without code we cannot help you. In normal cases users define theorem like structures in the preamble of their documents, and thus can choose what ever resulting name they want. If your document does not you need to tell us what else you have been doing. We ran out of crystal balls long ago

Comment: As long as there is no code help is difficult, but I think the `sharelatex` tag is completely wrong here!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{defn*}{Definitia}

\begin{document}
\begin{defn*}
    This is a definition.
\end{defn*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Definitia]

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Also, I'm sorry for the wrong tag, also for not inserting my code.